# Calculating % increase/decrease for a trend in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculation

very new to Python and pandas.
I have a data file which has a trend column (-1 for down, 0 for neutral and 1 for up) and a data column (sample below). I'm trying to calculate % increase/decrease for each of the trend segments in this file. For example row 1-8 it was -1.21% down, row 11-20 it was 0.40% up etc.

Tried to split the file in to a multiple files for each trend, but it is not really practical with really big file I have.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
trend,temp,,
-1,9.321,,
-1,9.305,,
-1,9.296,,
-1,9.288,,
-1,9.265,,
-1,9.241,,
-1,9.221,,
-1,9.208,,
0,9.201,,
0,9.198,,
1,9.203,,
1,9.206,,
1,9.21,,
1,9.215,,
1,9.218,,
1,9.223,,
1,9.25,,
1,9.28,,
1,9.235,,
1,9.241,,
-1,9.24,,
-1,9.237,,
-1,9.23,,
-1,9.227,,
-1,9.221,,
-1,9.217,,
-1,9.212,,
-1,9.208,,
-1,9.204,,
0,9.201,,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby` to find continuous groups and then transform them with custom function:

```
df['perc'] = df.groupby((df['trend'] != df['trend'].shift(1)).cumsum())['temp'].transform(lambda x:  (x.values[-1] - x.values[0])/(x.values[0])) * (df['trend'] != 0) * 100
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    trend   temp      perc
0  -1      9.321 -1.212316
1  -1      9.305 -1.212316
2  -1      9.296 -1.212316
3  -1      9.288 -1.212316
4  -1      9.265 -1.212316
5  -1      9.241 -1.212316
6  -1      9.221 -1.212316
7  -1      9.208 -1.212316
8   0      9.201 -0.000000
9   0      9.198 -0.000000
10  1      9.203  0.412909
11  1      9.206  0.412909
12  1      9.210  0.412909
13  1      9.215  0.412909
14  1      9.218  0.412909
15  1      9.223  0.412909
16  1      9.250  0.412909
17  1      9.280  0.412909
18  1      9.235  0.412909
19  1      9.241  0.412909
20 -1      9.240 -0.389610
21 -1      9.237 -0.389610
22 -1      9.230 -0.389610
23 -1      9.227 -0.389610
24 -1      9.221 -0.389610
25 -1      9.217 -0.389610
26 -1      9.212 -0.389610
27 -1      9.208 -0.389610
28 -1      9.204 -0.389610
29  0      9.201  0.000000
```

---

You can group then additionally:

```
print( df.groupby((df['trend'] != df['trend'].shift(1)).cumsum())['perc'].first() )
```

Prints:

```
trend
1   -1.212316
2   -0.000000
3    0.412909
4   -0.389610
5    0.000000
Name: perc, dtype: float64
```